# Rosdep fails with easy_install

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a set of self-defined rosdep rules which have been working nice until now. I need to install a package through easy_install, therefore my rosdep rule is:

```
 python-pkg:
   ubuntu:
     easy_install:
       packages: [my_pkg]
```

But this does not work:

```
$ rosdep update
$ rosdep resolve python-pkg
#apt
<empty_line>
```

I tried different combinations, such adding trusty, etc, but still rosdep is not able to find it.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Edit: If I use pip for instance it shows the rosdep resolve as expected, but not for easy_install. I am assuming there is support as it is said [here](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/rosdep_yaml_format.html)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237625/rosdep-fails-with-easy_install/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2016-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-21**:
Not an answer, but I'm not sure whether the `rosdep` documentation you're linking is still up-to-date. I seem to remember the support for package-specific `rosdep` rules (as was customary in the `rosbuild` days) being removed with the migration to catkin, but I could be wrong. Ping @Dirk Thomas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The docs were updated to remove the errant reference to easy_install: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/463 you should use the pip key.

easy_install does not have enough introspection to support the rosdep abstraction. (no instrospection) https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/pip_easy_install/ and pip can install all the same packages.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-06-23**:
Thanks for the reply. However, as far as I can tell pip cannot install all the same packages, it cannot install egg files. Example: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ortools/3.3629

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-06-23**:
Interesting, I didn't realize that. Though it looks like that doesn't have the same generality as pip packages as they're architecture specific.